# XPath and TXmlDocument

Tags: delphi, xpath, delphi-xe, txmldocument

In Delphi XE is it possible to use XPath with a [`TXmlDocument`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/XMLDoc.TXMLDocument) component?

I'm aware I can use late binding to access the MSXML2 and then use XPath:

```
XML := CreateOleObject('MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0') ;
XML.async := false;
XML.SetProperty('SelectionLanguage','XPath');
```

But I wanna know if [`TXmlDocument`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/XMLDoc.TXMLDocument) installed with Delphi XE supports XPath.

Comment: +1 for a good question; it turned out to be harder than I expected to find an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<strike>I can't find anything in the TXMLDocument documentation about XPath.</strike>

XML example, from the OmniXML XPath demo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title lang="slo">Z OmniXML v lepso prihodnost</title>
    <year>2006</year>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>Kwe sona standwa sam</title>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Try something like this:

```
uses 
  XMLDoc, XMLDom, XMLIntf;

// From a post in Embarcadero's Delphi XML forum.
function selectNode(xnRoot: IXmlNode; const nodePath: WideString): IXmlNode;
var
  intfSelect : IDomNodeSelect;
  dnResult : IDomNode;
  intfDocAccess : IXmlDocumentAccess;
  doc: TXmlDocument;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if not Assigned(xnRoot) or not Supports(xnRoot.DOMNode, IDomNodeSelect, intfSelect) then
    Exit;
  dnResult := intfSelect.selectNode(nodePath);
  if Assigned(dnResult) then
  begin
    if Supports(xnRoot.OwnerDocument, IXmlDocumentAccess, intfDocAccess) then
      doc := intfDocAccess.DocumentObject
    else
      doc := nil;
    Result := TXmlNode.Create(dnResult, nil, doc);
  end;
end;


var
  IDoc: IXMLDocument;
  INode: IXMLNode;
begin
  IDoc := LoadXMLDocument('.\books.xml');
  INode := SelectNode(IDoc.DocumentElement,'/bookstore/book[2]/title'); 
end;
```

Just as an FYI for others, I'll leave this in: [OmniXML](http://omnixml.com) supports XPath, and has a demo that shows really well how to use it. It's also free, comes with source, supports Unicode, and has pretty good support through it's forums.

Comment: Ken, many thnaks for your suggestion, but for now, I just want to know if is possible to use `TXMLDocument ` with `XPath`, avoiding the use of the third party components. ;)

Comment: @Salvador: Ok, if you insist. :)

Comment: So how do we set the Search namespaces? ie, setProperty('SelectionNamespaces', SearchNS);

Comment: @Robbie, I'm not sure. I haven't needed to do that, I'm afraid. You should post this as a new question of your own; you can always reference this answer as background (using the link available by right-clicking `share` below the answer and copying the link location).

Comment: NOTE: Asked new question on that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687619/how-to-use-xpath-on-txmldocument-while-using-namespaces

Comment: OmniXML has VERY limited support for XPath. Even to have simple `X<>Y` condition I had to patch the library. Kluug's OXML site has a speed shootout of some different XML libs for Delphi, so might be a starting point to explore alternatives.