# howto Fuzzy search the one of the xml value?

Tags: xml, delphi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="gb2312" ?> 
<allGreen> 
  <green> 
    <ID>1</ID> 
    <X>121.55443</X> 
    <Y>31.18068</Y> 
    <NAME> abc</NAME> 
    <HSNUM>108</HSNUM> 
  </green> 
  <green1> 
    <ID>2</ID> 
    <X>121.5067</X> 
    <Y>31.18833</Y> 
    <NAME>yyy</NAME> 
    <HSNUM>3683</HSNUM> 
  </green1>
  <green2> 
    <ID>2</ID> 
    <X>121.5067</X> 
    <Y>31.18833</Y> 
    <NAME> hahha</NAME> 
    <HSNUM>3683</HSNUM> 
    <STREET>heheh</STREET> 
  </green2> 
</allGreen>
```

thi is the test.xml

howto Fuzzy  search the  one of the NAME value?
uses xpath contains? or xpath matches?
/allGreen//NAME   ?  like this?

my english is poor , i mean fuzzy search  the name value for example, i fuzzy search use xpath the  string "abc" ? how to do that?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get your question. You want to parse this XML file and fuzzy search all of those places ? On maps or real fuzzy search using search engines like Google, Yahoo, Bing and whatever ?

Comment: my english is poor , i mean fuzzy search  the name value for example, i fuzzy search the  string "abc" ? how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use xpath search using delphi, here a very good example in how you can do this:

[XPath and TXmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383919/xpath-and-txmldocument)

I hope that helps.