# How to use query on XML file in Delphi?

Tags: xml, delphi

I am new in Delphi, and here is the thing I want to do. I have XML file formated like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Row>
        <Designation>1234102</Designation>
        <Inner>5.412</Inner>
        <Outer>3.588</Outer>
        <Spin>4.732</Spin>
        <Cage>0.399</Cage>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Designation>1342153</Designation>
        <Inner>5.916</Inner>
        <Outer>4.084</Outer>
        <Spin>5.277</Spin>
        <Cage>0.408</Cage>
    </Row>
    ........
</Data>
```

and I want to query it with Delphi. For example: I want data of  where  is 1342153. What is the best and easiest solution?

Thank in advance for example and explanation.

Comment: what do you mean by query ? why do you need that value and not the others ? will you ever want the other values too? which of them and why and how frequently ? there may be several solutions like DOM-parsers, SAX-parsers, XPATH, records-array de-serialization - but it is not known what actually you do need to do with XML.  http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: also edit your question please and below the text add the TAG with your specific delphi language version

Comment: My XML has around 6000 "rows" and I would like to read whole row not just designation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to make the presumption that once you find the `Designation`, you're going to want to also read the other entries (`Inner`, `Outer`, `Spin`, and `Cage`) that go with the designation.

`XPath` is the perfect solution for this problem. My example uses a new form with just a `TMemo` and `TButton` dropped on it, and adding a handler for the `Button1.OnClick` event:

```
uses
  MSXML, ComObj, ActiveX;

const
  XMLText =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>' +
             '<Data>' +
              '<Row>' +
                  '<Designation>1234102</Designation>' +
                  '<Inner>5.412</Inner>' +
                  '<Outer>3.588</Outer>' +
                  '<Spin>4.732</Spin>' +
                  '<Cage>0.399</Cage>' +
              '</Row>' +
              '<Row>' +
                 '<Designation>1342153</Designation>' +
                 '<Inner>5.916</Inner>' +
                  '<Outer>4.084</Outer>' +
                  '<Spin>5.277</Spin>' +
                  '<Cage>0.408</Cage>' +
              '</Row>' +
          '</Data>';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  XMLDoc: IXMLDOMDocument;
  Node, SibNode: IXMLDOMNode;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  XMLDoc := CoDOMDocument.Create;
  XMLDoc.loadXML(XMLText);

  // Select the node with the Designation you want.
  Node := XMLDoc.selectSingleNode('//Designation[text()="1342153"]');
  if Assigned(Node) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Found it.');
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Node.nodeName + ' = ' + Node.firstChild.nodeValue);

    // Read all the nodes at the same level as the Designation
    SibNode := Node.nextSibling;
    while SibNode <> nil do
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(SibNode.nodeName + ' = ' + 
                      SibNode.firstChild.nodeValue);
      Sib := Sib.nextSibling;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If you want to just grab all of the `<Row>` elements, and loop through the information they contain, you can use this (add a second button to the test app above, and use this for the `Button2.OnClick` handler):

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  XMLDoc: IXMLDOMDocument;
  NodeList: IXMLDOMNodeList;
  Node, SibNode: IXMLDOMNode;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  XMLDoc := CoDOMDocument.Create;
  XMLDoc.loadXML(XMLText);
  NodeList := XMLDoc.selectNodes('/Data/Row');
  if Assigned(NodeList) then
  begin
    for i := 0 to NodeList.length - 1 do
    begin
      Node := NodeList.item[i];
      SibNode := Node.firstChild;
      while Assigned(SibNode) do
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(SibNode.nodeName + ' = ' + 
                        SibNode.firstChild.nodeValue);
        SibNode := SibNode.nextSibling;
      end;
    end;
    // Add a blank line between groupings for readability
    Memo1.Lines.Add('');
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

As others suggested you can use XPath to find a particular value, in this case using this expression `/Data/Row/Designation[text()="1342153"]` will locate the node which contains the value 1342153 in the Designation.

Try this sample code

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  MSXML,
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj;

Const
 XmlStr =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'+
'<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'+
'    <Row>'+
'        <Designation>1234102</Designation>'+
'        <Inner>5.412</Inner>'+
'        <Outer>3.588</Outer>'+
'        <Spin>4.732</Spin>'+
'        <Cage>0.399</Cage>'+
'    </Row>'+
'    <Row>'+
'        <Designation>1342153</Designation>'+
'        <Inner>5.916</Inner>'+
'        <Outer>4.084</Outer>'+
'        <Spin>5.277</Spin>'+
'        <Cage>0.408</Cage>'+
'    </Row>'+
'</Data>';

procedure Test;
Var
  XMLDOMDocument  : IXMLDOMDocument;
  XMLDOMNode      : IXMLDOMNode;
begin
  XMLDOMDocument:=CoDOMDocument.Create;
  XMLDOMDocument.loadXML(XmlStr);
  XMLDOMNode := XMLDOMDocument.selectSingleNode('/Data/Row/Designation[text()="1342153"]');
  if XMLDOMNode<>nil then
   Writeln('Found');
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      Test;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

IXMLDocument and XPath are your friends when querying xml in Delphi
you can find many sources for that, e.g.
[XPath and TXmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383919/xpath-and-txmldocument)

Answer (score 0):

As you want to query the data from xml I recommend that you use the XML Transformation documented here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Converting_XML_Documents_into_Data_Packets

This will map you xml to a ClientDataSet the you can filter the records by the collumns you want or you can use DataBinding Wizard it has the explanation in the docs at this url  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Using_the_XML_Data_Binding_Wizard

For other ways to work with xml you can look at the main index of the doc's here
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Working_with_XML_documents_Index